# Why my json is returning attached with Promise in nodejs function?

Tags: node.js, promise

I have normal function call in server file.

```
let Val = fileName.load();
```

In Another file:

```
 const load = async function(){
  getVal = await getall();
  return getVal
 }
```

But I'm getting the response like,

```
 Promise{
  [{Values: valexampl}]
  }
```

Why my response is getting attached with Promise here. Kindly help me to understand

Comment: Also relevant: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function with `async` keyword in front of function definition returns the `Promise` type value.

So to get the value, you need to use `await` keyword like

```
let Val = await fileName.load();
```

Comment: The second piece of code is [pretty useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @Derek I cannot use await in the initial function. Even if I remove async also I'm getting the same response. Is there any other way? Please help.

Comment: Then you need to use like this. fileName.load().then((res) => { let Val = res; }) and inside `then` callback, do the rest.

Comment: @Derek.W thank you so much